# Problems setting ap a render farm

Tags: python, rendering, windows, network

I'm trying to set up Blender on our renderfarm.
Main problem is, we are using blade servers without a dedicated graphics card, so when starting Blender on the server I get this error:

*Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated Driver!
Your system does not use 3D hardware acceleration.
Blender requires a graphics driver with OpenGL 2.1 support.
This may be caused by:
A missing or faulty graphics driver installation.
Blender needs a graphics card driver to work correctly.
Accessing Blender through a remote connection.
using Blender through a virtual machine.
The program will now close.*

As a workaround I found this method:
Starting Blender on a workstation by configuring it to use "netrender" as an addon,
then saving two .blend-files, one for the master, one for the slave with the appropiate IP adress of the master.

Then launching Blender with no UI:

```
blender -b -y --addons netrender mastercfg.blend
blender -b -y --addons netrender slavecfg.blend
```

This is the following error message:

*C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender -b -y --addons netrender mastercfg.blend AL lib: (EE) ALCmmdevPlayback_resetProxy: Audio client returned buffer_len < period*2; expect break up found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\python read blend: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\mastercfg.blend Error, region type 2 missing in - name:"File", id:5 Blender quit*

So I came up with this one:

```
blender -b -y --python-console -P netrendermaster.py -noaudio -noglsl --addons netrender mastercfg.blend
blender -b -y --python-console -P netrenderslave.py -noaudio -noglsl --addons netrender slavecfg.blend
```

Following is the content of the .py-files:
netrendermaster.py:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module="netrender")
bpy.context.scene.network_render.mode = 'RENDER_MASTER'
bpy.context.scene.network_render.path = "/temp/"
bpy.context.scene.network_render.server_address = "172.20.20.19"
bpy.ops.render.netclientstart()
```

netrenderslave.py:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module="netrender")
bpy.context.scene.network_render.mode = 'RENDER_SLAVE'
bpy.context.scene.network_render.path = "/temp/"
bpy.context.scene.network_render.server_address = "172.20.20.19"
bpy.ops.render.netclientstart()
```

In the task manager I can see that blender is running and the log seems to be fine:

*C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>blender -b -y --python-console -P netrender.py -noaudio -noglsl --addons netrender mastercfg.blend found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\python Python 3.5.1 (default, Feb 17 2016, 17:09:19) [MSC v.1800 64 bit (AMD64)] on win 32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. (InteractiveConsole) >>>*

Sadly, connecting to the master is unsuccessful.
When building up a farm with the workstations as master, slave and clients I have no problem at all.
Firewall was disabled for the time of testing.

Any ideas on getting the farm started?

Cheers,
Michael